# How to get MVC Sitemap provider to security trim properly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvcsitemapprovider

I have the following sitemap XML using mvcsitemapprovider project.

It is not hiding the following node when all of the children are not accessible to the user:

```html
<mvcSiteMapNode url="~/Form.aspx" title="Form Editor" roles="ItemBank User" />
```

Instead it just shows an unclickable link titled "Forms".

How do you make MVCSitemapProvider hide the parent unclickable links when none of the children are visible to the end user?

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<mvcSiteMap xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns="http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/schemas/MvcSiteMap-File-4.0"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/schemas/MvcSiteMap-File-4.0 MvcSiteMapSchema.xsd">

  <mvcSiteMapNode url="~/Default.aspx" title="Web Site" roles="*" >
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Forms" clickable="false">
      <mvcSiteMapNode url="~/Form.aspx" title="Form Editor" roles="ItemBank User" />
      <mvcSiteMapNode url="~/FormHierarchy.aspx" title="Form Hiearchy" roles="ItemBank User" />
      <mvcSiteMapNode url="~/ContentCodeEditor.aspx" title="Content Code Editor" roles="ItemBank User"/>
      <mvcSiteMapNode url="~/FormCopy.aspx" title="Form Copy" roles="ItemBank User"/>
      <mvcSiteMapNode controller="Home" action="Index" area="Mvc" title="Mvc Area Non-Admin"/>
      <mvcSiteMapNode controller="Home" action="Index2" area="Mvc" title="Mvc Area Admin"/>
    </mvcSiteMapNode>
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Items" clickable="false" roles="ItemBank User">
      <mvcSiteMapNode url="~/Items.aspx" title="Item Editor" roles="ItemBank User" />
      <mvcSiteMapNode url="~/NewItem.aspx" title="New Item" roles="ItemBank User" />
      <mvcSiteMapNode url="~/ItemPairings.aspx" title="Item Pairings" roles="ItemBank User" />
      <mvcSiteMapNode url="~/ItemCopy.aspx" title="Item Copy" roles="ItemBank User" />
      <mvcSiteMapNode url="~/ContentReclassification.aspx" title="Content Reclassification" roles="ItemBank User"/>
    </mvcSiteMapNode>
  </mvcSiteMapNode>
</mvcSiteMap>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a `TrimEmptyGroupingNodesVisibilityProvider` for this specific purpose.

```
<mvcSiteMapNode url="~/Form.aspx" title="Form Editor" roles="ItemBank User" 
    visibilityProvider="MvcSiteMapProvider.TrimEmptyGroupingNodesVisibilityProvider, MvcSiteMapProvider" />
```

Reference: https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/issues/375

> NOTE: The default implementation requires the node to be non-clickable in order to work. However, you could make a custom visibility provider to handle this case.